# Query repo committed files order by commit date

Tags: libgit2sharp

I'd like to be able to have a collection of the files in the repo ordered by their commit date.

```
File       Committed
abc.bat    Dec 1 2013
bar.txt    Jan 1 2010
baz.cmd    Nov 8 2010
cru.zip    Feb 9 2012
```

How can I do this with LibGit2Sharp so that I can order by Commit Date?

The reason I need to do this is that LibGit2Sharp doesn't allow you to `.Pull()`, thereby merging changes. If that were the case, I'd go about with a `System.IO.DirectoryInfo` and query by modified date in Windows. It seems we only have `.Clone()`, which doesn't maintain those dates in the file system.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. There's nothing out of the box that would fit this need.

However, by walking the revision history backwards and identifying additions and modifications, one could gather the date of the latest change of each file that exist in the commit being examined.

**How about this?**

```
public void LetUsTryThis()
{
    using (var repo = new Repository(StandardTestRepoPath))
    {
        var referenceCommit = repo.Head.Tip;

        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, DateTimeOffset>> res = LatestChanges(repo, referenceCommit);

        foreach (KeyValuePair<string, DateTimeOffset> kvp in res)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} - {1}", kvp.Key, kvp.Value));
        }
    }
}

private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, DateTimeOffset>> LatestChanges(Repository repo, Commit referenceCommit)
{
    IDictionary<string, DateTimeOffset> dic = new Dictionary<string, DateTimeOffset>();

    var commitLog = repo.Commits.QueryBy(new CommitFilter { Since = referenceCommit })
                        .Concat(new[] { default(Commit) })
                        .Skip(1);

    var mostRecent = referenceCommit;

    foreach (Commit current in commitLog)
    {
        IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, DateTimeOffset>> res = ExtractAdditionsAndModifications(repo, mostRecent, current);
        AddLatest(dic, res);

        mostRecent = current;
    }

    return dic.OrderByDescending(kvp => kvp.Value);
}

private IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, DateTimeOffset>> ExtractAdditionsAndModifications(Repository repo, Commit next, Commit current)
{
    IDictionary<string, DateTimeOffset> dic = new Dictionary<string, DateTimeOffset>();

    var tc = repo.Diff.Compare(current == null ? null : current.Tree, next.Tree);

    foreach (TreeEntryChanges treeEntryChanges in tc.Added)
    {
        dic.Add(treeEntryChanges.Path, next.Committer.When);
    }

    foreach (TreeEntryChanges treeEntryChanges in tc.Modified)
    {
        dic.Add(treeEntryChanges.Path, next.Committer.When);
    }

    return dic;
}

private void AddLatest(IDictionary<string, DateTimeOffset> main, IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, DateTimeOffset>> latest)
{
    foreach (var kvp in latest)
    {
        if (main.ContainsKey(kvp.Key))
        {
            continue;
        }

        main.Add(kvp);
    }
}
```

Comment: @p.campbell Was this answer helpful?